# IE 11 compatibility errors using Angular 5

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

I have build my Angular application then run it in server.

I got errors that where not shown in localhost.

`Unable to get property 'onHover' of undefined or null reference.`

File *Chart.min.js, ligne : 10, colonne : 115187*

`Error “SCRIPT 1028 Expected identifier, string or number”`

File *polyfills.bundle.js, ligne : 6399, colonne : 5* .

`Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelector`

File  *styles.bundle.js, ligne : 215, colonne : 2*

`Expected identifier`

File: *vendor.bundle.js, ligne : 3169, colonne : 23*

I have uncommente imports in polyfills.ts

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';

//import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

Here's network trafic when loading app

[image]

Comment: And it works in other browsers?

Comment: Yes in Chrome and Firefox it's working

Comment: Then I guess the problem might be caused by polyfill being loaded too late?

Comment: I have added a screen shot of network trafic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add meta tag in the index.html. This is also a necessary line.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```